# wso2is5.3 : Send email notification

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to send email notification by my own way as the smtp parameters are not tenant wise in wso2is 5.3.0

I found a soap webservice to get the email template but the EmailTemplateDTO object is missing language and mail type (html or plain) properties.

The soap webservice I am using is `AccountCredentialMgtConfigServiceStub` and the method is `getEmailConfig()`.

Althougth, with this webservice I will have to replace placeholder by myself. Is there a webservice where I can pass the mailtemplate
and the username and/or claims to produce a ready to send email.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AccountCredentialMgtConfigService is the old way of managing email templates. That does not support HTML based templates.

In IS 5.3.0 it has been introduced new email template management component which supports HTML templates. You try it [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-event-handler-notification/tree/master/components/email-mgt).

You can follow [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Customizing+Automated+Emails) guide for understanding placeholders and user claims in email templates.

Thanks
Isura

Comment: Thanks, but how to replace placeholder manually if `Notification.Sending.Internally.Managed=false` ? Is there another WS to access mail created from mailTemplate with placeholder replaced ? Or a utility class with public methods ?

Comment: You can try https://localhost:9443/services/I18nEmailMgtConfigService?wsdl service